# replace string to space without using built in class or method

Tags: java, string, replace

I have

```
String  url =” http://@50stackoverflow.com/questions/@50724043/@50xyz.html ”
```

I want to replace @50 to space without using built in class or function.

What I want is

```
String url =” http:// stackoverflow.com/questions/ 724043/ xyz.html ”
```

Comment: Why would you *not* want to use a built-in class or function? Heck, you've got to use *some* built-in classes or functions, or you won't be able to get at the string data anyway...

Comment: Is this homework?? consider adding the homework tag to your question if so.

Comment: you meant you don't want to use `.replaceAll` pre-defined function??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
char[] realString = "http://@50stackoverflow.com/questions/@50724043/@50xyz.html".toCharArray();
String newString = "";
for (int i = 0; i < realString.length; i++) {
    if (i<realString.length-2 && realString[i] == '@' && realString[i+1] == '5' && realString[i+2] == '0') {
        newString = newString + " ";
        i=i+3;
    } else {
        newString = newString + realString[i];
    }
}
System.out.println(newString);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a very weird question, why not using the tools java have? 
is "for" is build in? is String is build in?
any way, is this good enough not-java-solution? (please don't use this code anywhere)

```
char[] url = "http://@50stackoverflow.com/questions/@50724043/@50xyz.html".toCharArray();
    String output = "";
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < url.length - 3; i++) {
        if (url[i] == '@' && url[i+1] == '5' && url[i+2] == '0') {
            output += " ";
            i+=3;
        } else {
            output += url[i];
        }
    }
    for (;i < url.length; i++) {
        output += url[i];
    }
    System.out.println(output);
```